# win32com moving between Styles in a Selectoin

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I'm attempting to programmatically write a Word file and am struggling to alternate styles on a selection object. Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
objWord = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
objSel = objWord.Selection
writestuff = "\r\nSome Heading"
objSel.Style = objWord.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3")
objSel.TypeText(writestuff)
#This works so far, we have a heading and some text, now we want to write data below the heading
objSel.Style = objWord.ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal") #Setting style back to 'Normal' for next section
writestuff = "\r\nSome data about the heading we just wrote") 
objSel.TypeText(writestuff)
#At this point the heading and new text both go to the 'Normal' style.
```

It appears that my 'selection' is affecting all of the document, however, when I make my initial objSel.Style assignment to 'Heading 3' previous lines aren't affected. When I switch back to normal everything else is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that what I needed to do (or at least one of the things which will solve this problem) is to add a `TypeParagraph()` method

Corrected code looks like this:

```
objWord = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
objSel = objWord.Selection
writestuff = "\r\nSome Heading"
objSel.Style = objWord.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3")
objSel.TypeText(writestuff)
objSel.TypeParagraph ##THIS IS WHAT I ADDED, NO NEED TO READJUST STYLE##
writestuff = "\r\nSome data about the heading we just wrote") 
objSel.TypeText(writestuff)
```

This would present data with the correct heading and then normal-type text on the following line.